# I have an odd location config for nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm auditing my nginx configs and a lot of them have this in them

```
location ~* \favicon.ico$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 1d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Is this just for the favicon.ico file? and is there any point in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means:

Access to files ending with `favicon.ico` (case-insensitive) will not be logged.
The responses should be cached in browsers and proxies for max 1 day.

Comment: is there is a good reason to do this for a favicon separately from the other images?

Comment: If your caching requirements are different for it, then it is the reason. Otherwise nope.